# 17.10 - Closing applications on lock

Tags: 17.10, lock-screen, wakeup

I lock (Super-L) and when I log in again is like I've restarted the computer. All applications are closed and the network is disconnected.

Is that a configuration or a bug?

Comment: Sounds like a bug!